# Use JavaScript in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Want to show theme corresponding the user's operating system theme settings.

For that, need to use Javascript in css like below but it will cause error

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  localStorage.setItem("os-prefered-dark", true)
}
```

Comment: you cannot use javascript in CSS. but you can use some css in javascript.

Comment: Never seen people using JavaScript in CSS but CSS in JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, I do believe [this article](https://gosink.in/javascript-css-toggle-dark-light-theme-based-on-your-users-preferred-scheme/) will help you. :)

Comment: Why set the dark theme in localStorage?

Comment: So that the theme preference remains there after the page is also refreshed

Comment: Then why use `prefers-color-scheme`? As you can just access that again

Comment: So that we can show the theme as per user's operating system also

Comment: Consider only accessing `prefers-color-scheme`. Saving that value to localStorage is unnecessary.

Comment: I am giving two options, the user can manually also change the theme, after which it will overwrite prefers-color-theme. So to save this user manual theme, have to save it in local storage